# How to use django-channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I need to use websocket in django, so I read docs of channels. Now I know the basic concepts but still confused because there's few code in detail.


Here are  my questions:

How can I make ASGI align with the WSGI in code? In other words, how to configure `WSGI Server to ASGI` or `ASGI to WSGI application`?

Does it affect the way of using ajax?

Does it affect that if the django sends http request to other website?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Too broad to answer.. can you narrow down what is your specific problem. Django channels comes with optional wsgi adapter so you can use that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use new ASGI spec then define `CHANNEL_LAYERS` in `settings.py`. If you are not set then this just run and work like a normal WSGI app.

When you set above ( `to ASGI` ) you have two options, either route all traffic through ( in this case `HTTP/Websocket` ) to interface server ( `daphne` ). Or you can route all the websockets and long polling http connection to interface server

[Deploying](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html?highlight=wsgi#deploying)  document here if you want to take look

Comment: Just found a example here:[link](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django)<br>It use `'http.request': StaticFilesConsumer()` but says this isn't ideal. So what's the ideal way to direct `http.request` to `views.py?` It will be very kind of you if you show some simple code....

Comment: Running above all your http.request direct to `views.py` only! Did you experience any issues ?

Comment: I know the concepts but don't know how to write. The word `direct` is a little abstract...And I try to use `'http.request': StaticFilesConsumer()` but encountered with 403 error, maybe that's another question...

Comment: I know where the 403 comes from. Post needs csrftoken but the cookie is null. The django csrf middleware is supposed to set csrftoken but why the cookie doesn't get to client?

Comment: 403 problem solved. And `'http.request': StaticFilesConsumer()` works fine. But what's the ideal way to direct? Last question, thank you very much!

Comment: Before can you please give me any reference about the `StaticFilesConsumer` ?

Comment: Oh... Actually ASGI can direct all your `htt.request` to views by default.. why you are writing `StaticFilesConsumer` ? this `StaticFilesConsumer` what this do ? And one more thing.,.. Are you trying to serve `css, js` via channels ?

Comment: Because `StaticFilesConsumer` is used in the example [link](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django). And there's comment says that this makes Django serve static files from settings.STATIC_URL. I'm using channels for homework.... Why I didn't notice that `http.request` can be directed by default in docs..... Thanks a lot.